# C++ polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am having a weird problem, which I'm sure has an easy fix. I have a super class let's call it "Bird". Bird has a virtual function called chirp, which returns me 0. I also have a subclass lets call it...SomeOtherBird. SomeOtherBird is a subclass of Bird. The chirp() function for my subclass is supposed to return me 1.

So far:

Bird.Chirp() should return 0
SomeOtherBird.Chirp() should return 1

Some other bird is a subclass of bird.

Now assuming I pass in Bird into a seperate constructor, let's call it nest.

So: nest(Bird& x)

if I pass a SomeOtherBird in, and I call Chirp, it calls the virtual function of the main super-class and not of the subclass, so for example:

SomeOtherBird x;
Nest(x);
and then if I do x.chirp, the main method is called, not the one of the subclass.

How do I get the function in the sub-class to be called, and not the virtual main function?

Thanks

Comment: Also, include the actual code you're having trouble with, not some roundabout description.

Comment: Dynamic Dispatch should work and it should return 1, unless you are doing something else. Post your entire code

Answer (score 1):

I worked for me.

[ideone.com/RRfau](http://ideone.com/RRfau)

You really ought to include some example code with questions like this so we can help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo> 

class Bird
{
public:
   virtual ~Bird() {}
   virtual int chirp() { return 0; }
};

class SomeOtherBird : public Bird
{
public:
   virtual int chirp() { return 1; }
};

void nest( Bird& x )
{
   std::cout << typeid(x).name() << " says " << x.chirp() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   SomeOtherBird s;
   nest( s );

   Bird b;
   nest( b );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine as shown below. Perhaps you might not have made the base method virtual. Or there is something else wrong in the code, since the code was not posted, it is impossible to tell.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bird
{
public:
    Bird() {}
    ~Bird() {}
    virtual int Chrip() { cout << "Bird version" << endl; return 0; }
};

class SomeOtherBird:public Bird
{
 public:
    SomeOtherBird() {}
    ~SomeOtherBird() {}
    virtual int Chrip() { cout << "SomeOtherBird version" << endl; return 1; }
};

int nest(Bird &b)
{
    b.Chrip();
}

int main()
{
    SomeOtherBird s;
    Bird &b = s;
    int retcode = nest(b);
    cout << "retcode " << retcode << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
rhdevblade1-~/cpp: ./virt
SomeOtherBird version
retcode 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code it's impossible to answer you for sure. However, this sounds like you did not write "virtual Bird()" in your base class, only in the derived class. That doesn't work.

```
class Bird {
virtual int Bird();
};

class MoreBird : public Bird {
int Bird();
};
```

The virtual keyword is not required in the deriving class (although it is not good practice not to put it there even if 99.9% of the programmers are lazy and don't do it.)

Comment: You might want to gloss over your code again, `Bird()` is a constructor.

Comment: i.e. you can't have a virtual constructor.

Comment: Good one 8-) I see others have followed with the correct code anyway.